# The signature key was not found error when using IndentityServer4 with Angular, AspNet Core

Tags: angular, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

I've 3 projects in my solution one is Idp using `IdentityServer4` with the following configuration. I'm using `Implicit Flow`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "damienbodserver.pfx"), "");


    // Add framework services.
    var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgreSQLConnectionString");
    Console.WriteLine(connectionString);
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    //NB added for implicit flow
    services.AddCors();

    services.AddMvc();

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();

    services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, AppClaimsPrincipalFactory>();


    services.AddIdentityServer()
        //.AddTemporarySigningCredential()
        .AddSigningCredential(cert)
        .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityServerStatics.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(IdentityServerStatics.GetApiResources())
        .AddClientStore<CustomClientStore>() // Add the custom client store
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddProfileService<CustomProfileService>(); // use custom profile service to pull in claims

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("MyUMD_User", policy => policy.RequireClaim("MyUMD:AccessLevel", "User", "Manage", "Support", "Admin"));
    });
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("MyUMD_Manage", policy => policy.RequireClaim("MyUMD:AccessLevel", "Manage", "Support", "Admin"));
    });
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("MyUMD_Support", policy => policy.RequireClaim("MyUMD:AccessLevel", "Support", "Admin"));
    });
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("MyUMD_Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("MyUMD:AccessLevel", "Admin"));
    });
}
```

and the resource server is configured as below.

**NOTE** this resource server is already working with custom JWT token generation and validation. Now I want to add additional capability to read the claims from the token generated by `IdentityServer4`

```
public void ConfigureJwtAuthService(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var folderForKeyStore = Configuration["Production:KeyStoreFolderWhichIsBacked"];
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "damienbodserver.pfx"), "");

        // Important The folderForKeyStore needs to be backed up.
        services.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName("vast_webapplication")
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(_env.ContentRootPath))
            .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(cert);



        var symmetricKeyAsBase64 = "Y2F0Y2hlciUyMHdvbmclMjBsb3ZlJTIwLm5ldA==";
        var keyByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(symmetricKeyAsBase64);
        var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyByteArray);

        // JWT Token signing settings
        TokenAuthOptions tokenAuth = new TokenAuthOptions()
        {
            Audience = "vast-audience",
            Issuer = "vast-issuer",
            // this gets set later in Configure
            SigningCredentials = null,
            Key = signingKey
        };

        // add the auth options to the DI container
        services.AddSingleton(tokenAuth);

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // The signing key must match!
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,

            // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = "vast-issuer",

            // Validate the JWT Audience (aud) claim
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = "vast-audience",

            // Validate the token expiry
            ValidateLifetime = true,

            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
        };

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
           o.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
        });
        //.AddCookie(options=> options.Cookie.Domain="localhost:5000");


        services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            //options.DefaultPolicy= new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();

            options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationPolicies.TicketTypeRead, policy => {
                policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                policy.RequireClaim(CustomClaims.TicketTypRead);
            });


            string[] roles = new string[] { "User", "Management" };
            options.AddPolicy("Reporting_Managers", policy =>
            {
                policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                policy.RequireClaim("SkyBusReporting:Reporting", "Management");
            });

        });
    }
```

Angular app is also a .net project and it successfully calls the api (resource server function). In response I received a 401 Unauthorized status and in the header I can see this

> www-authenticate →Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The
>   signature key was not found"

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I didn't see where you pointed the API/resource server to the IndentityServer4 implementation.

Comment: I don't need to. My Angular app is pointed to the idp and on home page load angular app redirects the page to idp login page. After login idp redirects back to angular home page with bearer token. I only need to configure the jwt token reader in resource api to read the claims.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by use IdentityServer4 in the resource API then?

Comment: yeah u r write I don't need idp in resource api I only need the public key to read the token in resource api

Comment: So you are wanting to call an api that isn’t a client of the IdentityServer4 and read the claims from the bearer token, correct?

Comment: yes that is what i want and i think with this discussion i found the issue :)

Comment: Awesome, post you answer and accept it. I would clarify your question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks to [aaronR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6835380/aaronr)  i figured out the issue in my code. Now I'm not sure if this is the best way to implement the `implicit flow`

I changed my code is resource api to use the public key from the certificate to read the token which is missing in the above code.

In the `ConfigureJwtAuthService` function above I changed the code to get a key from the certificate as below

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "damienbodserver.pfx"), "");
        X509SecurityKey key = new X509SecurityKey(cert);
        SigningCredentials credentials = new SigningCredentials(key, "RS256");
```

than I used this key in `TokenValidationParameters` object as below

```
var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // The signing key must match!
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            //IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
            IssuerSigningKey = key,

            // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidIssuer = "vast-issuer",

            // Validate the JWT Audience (aud) claim
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidAudience = "vast-audience",

            // Validate the token expiry
            ValidateLifetime = true,

            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
        };
```

I also changed the implementation of custom JWT Token generation to use the same key and credentials to generate the JWT Token.